# Unit Testing Portable Class Library for Windows Store fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I'm currenty unit testing a pcl which references System.Net.Http.
The WP8 Unit test runs fine but the unit test for windows store crashes at "_httpClient.GetAsync(path).Result;" with the exception "TaskCanceledException".

If I call the function from the pcl from a normal app for windows store it works fine! And yes, the required capability "Internet" is set.

I would like to reuse my unit test code and don't have to write it twice for both plattforms. Has someone had a similar problem or knows whats going on?

Also trying to get a normal app for windows store to run unit tests doesn't seem to work. All tests crash with the message "Failed to activate Windows Store app unit test executor".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the code to recreate this?

Comment: So, I think you should be using fakes for this. You shouldn't be attempting to actually retrieve HTTP results, you should be adding a fake and having it return all of the possible results that could be returned. Create one test which responds to each result by inputting a fake designed to return said result. This will help you test the processing of the response (which is what you should be testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was an easy one. The unit test doesn't run in the UI thread while my normal code did. So using .Result created a deadlock where the ui thread was waiting on the ui thread. Very stupid error :/